# Finding common elements from two lists of lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of lists containing some 3D coordinates like this (for example):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 2, 3]]
b[0] = [[11, 22, 3], [12, 34, 6], [41, 2, 34], [198, 213, 536], [1198, 1123, 1156]]
b[1] = [[11, 22, 3], [42, 25, 64], [43, 45, 23]]
b[2] = [[3, 532, 23], [4, 5, 6], [98, 23, 56], [918, 231, 526]]
b[n] = [[11, 22, 3], [42, 54, 36], [41, 2432, 34]]
```

What will be a fast way of finding if any of the elements of "b" have any coordinate in the list "a"? For example, in the given example "a[2]" and "b[2][1]" are the same and so I want the program to return "true".

Comment: Did you mean `a[1]` and `b[2][1]` in your question?

Comment: yes, sorry! I will edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the innermost lists of `b` into a set(`s`), and then iterate over `a` to check whether any item in `a` exist in `s` or not.

```
tot_items_b = sum(1 for x in b for y in x) #total items in b
```

Sets provide an `O(1)` lookup, so the overall complexity is going to be :

`O(max(len(a), tot_items_b))`

```
def func(a, b):
   #sets can't contain mutable items, so convert lists to tuple while storing

   s = set(tuple(y) for x in b for y in x)
   #s is set([(41, 2, 34), (98, 23, 56), (42, 25, 64),...])

   return any(tuple(item) in s for item in a)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 2, 3]]
>>> b = [[[11, 22, 3], [12, 34, 6], [41, 2, 34], [198, 213, 536], [1198, 1123, 1156]], [[11, 22, 3], [42, 25, 64], [43, 45, 23]], [[3, 532, 23], [4, 5, 6], [98, 23, 56], [918, 231, 526]]]
>>> func(a,b)
True
```

Help on `any`:

```
>>> print any.__doc__
any(iterable) -> bool

Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.
If the iterable is empty, return False.
```

Use set intersection to get all the common elements:

```
>>> s_b = set(tuple(y) for x in b for y in x)
>>> s_a = set(tuple(x) for x in a)
>>> s_a & s_b
set([(4, 5, 6)])
```

Comment: is it possible to edit this program to output the common element? thank you!

Comment: @jhaprade first common element or all of them?

Comment: I believe the complexity is `O(max(len(a), sum_{i=0}^{len(b)-1}{len(b[i])}))` since when creating the `set` you are doing a nested loop.

Comment: @Ashwini I would like to have all of them if possible.

Comment: @Bakuriu Whoops! good point. But I didn't understand the notation you're using?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary It should be a LaTeX-like formula(sum over the indices of b of the length of b elements i.e. total number of elements inside b).

Comment: `sum(1 for x in b for y in x)` can be `sum(len(x) for x in b)`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the list first, then simply iterate through it:

```
>>> B = [[[11, 22, 3], [12, 34, 6], [41, 2, 34], [198, 213, 536], [1198, 1123, 1156]], [[11, 22, 3], [42, 25, 64], [43, 45, 23]], [[3, 532, 23], [4, 5, 6], [98, 23, 56], [918, 231, 526]], [[11, 22, 3], [42, 54, 36], [41, 2432, 34]]]
>>> A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 2, 3]]
>>> for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(B):
...     if i in A:
...             print True, i
... 
True [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: @Jared Fast way to flatten the list

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy
b=[ [], [] , [] ]
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 2, 3]]
b[0] = [[11, 22, 3], [12, 34, 6], [41, 2, 34], [198, 213, 536], 
        [1198, 1123, 1156]]
b[1] = [[11, 22, 3], [42, 25, 64], [43, 45, 23]]
b[2] = [[3, 532, 23], [4, 5, 6], [98, 23, 56], [918, 231, 526]]

for p1 in a:
    for p2 in [ p for bb in b for p in bb]:
        v=numpy.linalg.norm(numpy.array(p1)-numpy.array(p2))
        if v == 0: print p1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 2, 3]]
b={}
b[0] = [[11, 22, 3], [12, 34, 6], [41, 2, 34], [198, 213, 536], [1198, 1123, 1156]]
b[1] = [[11, 22, 3], [42, 25, 64], [43, 45, 23]]
b[2] = [[3, 532, 23], [4, 5, 6], [98, 23, 56], [918, 231, 526]]
b[3] = [[11, 22, 3], [42, 54, 36], [41, 2432, 34]]

for i in b:
    for ii in i:
        if ii in a:
            return True
```

It works but I don't sure it's fast or not.

Comment: It would be faster with `any` and a generator - `any(ii in a for i in b for ii in i)`, but it probably still won't compete with the answer using sets (except possibly for very small input sizes). It *might* compete with the `itertools.chain` solution, but will probably still be a bit slower.

Comment: @lvc Compete? Hey now, this isn't a competition. I'm just supplying my answer because it's another way to answer the question.

Comment: You should initialise `b` as a list: `b = []`, not dict.  otherwise in the loop `for ii in i:` you're actually trying to iterate over an integer.